# Regular expression in Pandas: Get substring between a space and a colon

Tags: python, pandas, substring, slice

I have a Pandas dataframe with the column `store`.  It contains a list of stores that look like this:

```
H-E-B 721:1101 W STAN SCHLUETER LOOP,KILLEEN,TX
H-E-B PLUS 39:2509 N MAIN ST,BELTON,TX
```

I want the store number, which are `721` and `39` in the above examples.

Here is my process for getting it:

1. Find the position of the colon.
2. Slice backwards until reaching a space.

How do I do this in Python/Pandas? I'm guessing that I need to use regex, but I have no idea how to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `str.extract` with the `(\d+):` regex:

```
df['number'] = df['store'].str.extract('(\d+):', expand=False).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
                                             store  number
0  H-E-B 721:1101 W STAN SCHLUETER LOOP,KILLEEN,TX     721
1           H-E-B PLUS 39:2509 N MAIN ST,BELTON,TX      39
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yikzhs/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can apply a function to the store column

```py
def retrieve_store_number(text):
    return text.split(":")[0].split()[-1]

df["store_number"] = df.store.apply(retrieve_store_number)
```

Answer (score 1):

To use regex in Pandas, you can use the [extract](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) function:

```
df['store_number'] = df['store'].str.extract(r'(\d+(?=:))')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something along those lines:

```
def extract_number(string: str) -> int:
    return [int(i.split(":")[0]) for i in string.split(" ") if ":" in i][0]
df = pd.DataFrame([["H-E-B 721:1101 W STAN SCHLUETER LOOP,KILLEEN,TX"],
                   ["H-E-B PLUS 39:2509 N MAIN ST,BELTON,TX"]], columns = ["store"])
df["number"] = df["store"].apply(extract_number)
```